# What's more preferable: "method of obtaining" or "method to obtain"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference, infinitive-vs-gerund

In a scientific paper one describes a method to obtain some sort of formulas. But one always write "method of obtaining". Isn't it less natural then to write "method to obtain", or these are two equally usable wordings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually use the construction method + of +  doing.  You can also use the structure method + for + doing.  Method + to infinitive, though not incorrect, is rarely used.

So you should say method of obtaining or method for obtaining.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Macmillan dictionary it is **method of**, in fact **method to** isn't even listed there http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/method